# Python 3 - Print Syntax Error

Tags: python-3.x

I know now in Python 3 Print is a function, but my print, I believe, is in accordance with the syntax, but still giving error Syntax

```
print (json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

The output

```
print ((json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The syntax is fine. Is there anything before that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the debugger shows at the print while saying that  it is an SyntaxError, then you mostly forgot a bracket in the line before it.
Can we see some more lines? Like 1 or 2 before it?

Edit: Just an example [image]

Comment: data = json.loads((request_until_succeed(url).decode('utf-8'))
    print (json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

Comment: Yeah you forgot the last bracket :D Just add an bracket at the end and you should be fine ^^